# downcase a value in JSON

Tags: json, jq, lowercase

I have a json file and I'm looking to lowercase PART of a value - I can jq the value and lower case the string but how do I ensure this new lowercase value gets added back into the whole file?

```
jq '.[].Id' file.json | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

the above only lower cases the ID value's but now I also need to write those back into their correct spots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [update operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:|=) with [`ascii_downcase`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ascii_downcase,ascii_upcase) builtin.

```
jq '.[].Id |= ascii_downcase' file
```