Case-insensitive check in `jq` for equality
I found the following on the govc govmomi github pages, which allows me to search for VMs by MAC address:
govc object.collect -json -type m / config.hardware.device \
  | jq -r '
      .
      | select(.ChangeSet[].Val.VirtualDevice[].MacAddress == "00:50:56:bc:5e:3c")
      | [.Obj.Type, .Obj.Value]
      | join(":")
    ' \
  | xargs govc ls -L

Please find attached a snippet of govc output that should suffice:
{
  "Obj": {
    "Type": "VirtualMachine",
    "Value": "vm-666"
  },
  "ChangeSet": [
    {
      "Val": {
        "VirtualDevice": [
          {
          },
          {
            "MacAddress": "00:50:56:bc:5e:3c"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

The problem I'm facing is that some MACs contain upper, some lower case letters, and I don't know ahead of time which machine uses which scheme.
I can't figure out how to make the == case insensitive.
I have found answers here on stackoverflow that suggest using ascii_downcase as a filter, but I don't know how to apply that w/ the ==.
The syntax suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454688 gives me a sequence of explode input must be a string errors (1 per line of govc output).
In case this matters for this exercise: this is happening on Mac OS 15.1, jq is installed via brew, version is 1.7.1.

@tink: Can you make your question more reproducible by providing an example of govc object.collect -json -type m / config.hardware.device, so that we can test ideas instead of posting guesses for you to try?

@Phil - I have, both with and without the single = behind the |, both give me explode input must be a string for each line of input.

@ruakh I'll try to provide anonymised output for one VM (may have to trim it significantly, it's very garrulous).  Give me a few minutes.

FWIW, echo '[{"name": "ABC"}, {"name": "DEF"}]' | jq '.[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "abc")' successfully selects only the object whose name is "ABC". So if the code that you've posted works fine aside from being case-sensitive, then I do think that simply inserting | ascii_downcase should work.

@ruakh - not sure what I'm doing wrong, even w/ the santised snippet above I get the explode input must be a string message - not per line, as I initially thought, though, but once per returned object.

Ah, thanks for adding that input. The issue has to do with the object that doesn't have a MacAddress field; I get the same error from echo '[{}, {"name": "ABC"}, {"name": "DEF"}]' | jq '.[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "abc")'.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


it outputs the names of every vm, whether they have that MAC or not ...

Each …[] in .ChangeSet[].Val.VirtualDevice[].MacAddress creates a stream of potentially more than one result. In the sample given, .ChangeSet[] produces one item, and (for each of them) .Val.VirtualDevice evaluates to two items, creating a combined stream of two items. If you want to reduce this stream to a binary decision (zero or one items only), use an aggregate function that performs this conversion. For example, if you want select to return with one item if at least one of them passes the test, use the any function.
(Also, I'm preferring strings over // "", so items without a .MacAddress are filtered out immediately instead of replacing them with an empty string that only fails after when compared to another literal string.)
select(any(
  .ChangeSet[].Val.VirtualDevice[].MacAddress | strings;
  ascii_downcase == "00:50:56:bc:5e:3c"
))
| [.Obj.Type, .Obj.Value]
| join(":")

VirtualMachine:vm-666

Demo

Made up some more test data and tried it, works like a charm w/ both upper and lower, and with entries w/o MacAddress! Thank you!

Assuming that normalizing MacAddress to ascii_downcase would be sufficient,   one approach would be to add a pre-processing filter using walk like so:
walk(if type == "object" and has("MacAddress") 
     then .MacAddress |= ascii_downcase end)

You might want a more targeted approach, but the above can still serve as a guide. (*)
Another approach would be to use regexp-based matching with the "i" option to "ignore case", i.e. test(_,"i").  This would be the recommended approach in cases where ascii_downcase doesn't cut the mustard.

(*) If your jq is sufficiently antiquated, you'd have to include else . as well.

Thanks, I'll test this out tomorrow when I'm back at work.


The suggested dupe's syntax gives me a sequence of explode input must be a string errors (1 per line of govc output).

That's because one of your devices doesn't have the MacAddress field, and ascii_downcase only supports strings, not null.
To fix this, you can use // "" [doc link] to default to the empty string, and then pass that through ascii_downcase:
govc object.collect -json -type m / config.hardware.device \
  | jq -r '
      .
      | select(.ChangeSet[].Val.VirtualDevice[].MacAddress // "" | ascii_downcase == "00:50:56:bc:5e:3c")
      | [.Obj.Type, .Obj.Value]
      | join(":")
    ' \
  | xargs govc ls -L


Thank you for trying!  So, the explode error is gone, but now it outputs the names of every vm, whether they have that MAC or not ... and a few jq: error (at <stdin>:554): Invalid path expression with result ""

@tink: That's why it's so important to provide good sample input, instead of hoping that folks will correctly guess what your data looks like . . .

Fair enough re invalid path, but I still would have expected only to see lines that actually match?

@tink: Re: line-wise matching instead of object-wise matching: You provided code that had a certain behavior, and you said that the code behaved as you wanted aside from the case-sensitivity issue. Why would you expect an answer to change to a different behavior that you gave no indication of wanting? (I mean, it's moot now, obviously. And it's not a huge deal. But in the future, I'd ask that you be a bit more respectful of answerers' time, by putting a bit more effort into writing the question.)

I hear what you're saying and agree. The thing is that I didn't get any messages about missing paths with the original invocation, and wasn't aware of those until I tried your version. Had I redirected the entire govc query resultset I'd have been looking through a giant haystack not knowing what I'm looking for. Only through this exercise I learnt that vSphere creates one dynamic VM per host that doesn't have a MAC address. Anyway, I'll try harder.
